# Nothing is rendering in root id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

nothing is rendering on my page and i'm quite confused. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../layout/Header/Header";
import Footer from "../layout/Footer/Footer.jsx";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import NotFound from "./NotFound";

import Home from "../pages/Home";
import Pricing from "../pages/Pricing";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact";
import About from "../pages/About";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard";
import Signin from "../pages/Signin";


class App extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Router>
            <App />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route exact path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
              <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
              <Redirect from="/" to="home" />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import App from "./components/App/App";

//import Signup from "components/pages/SignupBRUH";
import "./styles/styles.scss";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

My project is also using passport, if that helps with anything. This might be an error with routes or something. I don't know.

Would be awesome if someone could solve this for me, thanks.

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: Nothing besides:
GET /home 304 4.245 ms - -
GET /js/app.js 200 4.564 ms - -
Whenever i reload the page

Comment: Is your HTML static or is it being built by a plugin? If so, have you checked the element with `id="root"` is there and that you're app script it being imported?

Comment: Yeah it has an id of root:
<div id="root"></div>

Comment: I'm using webpack, idk if that helps

Comment: Can you please show the content of Header , Footer and Home components

Comment: If you change your `return` in your `<App>` to a simple text, does that work? This will help you narrow the bug to "Content issues VS Configuration issues"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try rendering the below for App component, to make sure the template is wired up correctly

```
class App extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
            App Component
          </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```